# "full balance due" vs "statement balance" vs "pay in full"

Tags: united-states, credit-card, interest-rate, payment, online-payment

I wanted to pay off my credit card, and at the "Select Payment Option" screen at my bank presents the following options:

=============

- MINIMUM ($163.00)
- MINIMUM PLUS PAST DUE ($163.00)
- TWICE PAYMENT DUE ($326.00)
- STATEMENT BALANCE ($9,340.56)
- PAY IN FULL ($9,426.81)
- FULL BALANCE DUE ($9,316.93)
- CUSTOM

================

So, I'd like to know detailed difference between these 3:

- STATEMENT BALANCE ($9,340.56)
- PAY IN FULL ($9,426.81)
- FULL BALANCE DUE ($9,316.93)

and why their numbers are all different. Aren't these the same things (especially STATEMENT BALANCE and FULL BALANCE DUE)?
When I pay my credit cards at other banks, I don't see as many options.

Thank you

Comment: Have you considered asking the provider?

Comment: I *have* asked the bank. While I am waiting for their response, I asked here as well since that's not against the rules and since bank reps can give wildly inaccurate answers, from my personal experience, so it makes sense to source knowledge from several places.

Comment: It would help to know what bank it is and in what country...

Comment: If you intend to continue to use your credit card after you've paid it off, make sure you pay it off in a way that restores the interest-free grace period (assuming it has one).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@littleadv was very close, but it's a little more idiosyncratic (I have not made a payment yet, and there were no refunds).
As I anticipated, my bank's first rep who answered my email was clueless and failed to even mention `Full Balance Due` despite that being the biggest part of my well-written question to the bank.

I demanded escalation, and here is the response from the second rep:

> To clarify the 3 payment options you are inquiring about, the full balance due is the starting statement balance. The starting statement balance is any purchases made during the statement period (10/22-11/21) and other purchases and interest that carried over from the previous statement period (9/22-10/21). The statement balance is the starting balance minus payments made during the period, plus purchases and interest over the period. Pay in full is the option to pay the current amount of interest accrued. Which is the statement balance plus interest accrued since the closing date of the statement period.

So, basically, the crux of the problem is their confusing nomenclature for `Full Balance Due`. Despite its name leading folks (me included) to believe that it is more significant than the `Statement Balance`, it's actually less than that -- it's just the Statement Balance, but without the payments and interest that occurred during the statement period.

Here is a visual aid I created for myself:

(It contains no purchases because I haven't made any on that card in a long time.)

[image: visual scheme]

I've never seen other banks use `Full Balance Due`, and I am not sure what its purpose is (especially with the name like that) other then sowing confusion, apparently even amongst the lower-level reps of my bank. With my other banks, it's always just these simple four: Minimum Due, Statement Balance, Pay in Full, and Custom.

Answer (score 20):

You might want to wait for a confirmation from your bank, but my experience with a couple of credit unions was this:

> STATEMENT BALANCE ($9,340.56)

This was the total balance as posted on the last statement that was issued to you (a specific date in the past).

> FULL BALANCE DUE ($9,316.93)

This is the total balance as posted right now, on the date of the query. It being less than the statement balance shows that you've made a payment, or maybe there was a refund or another type of credit that posted on your account since the statement date.

> PAY IN FULL ($9,426.81)

This is what you actually owe. This is the current balance due + *interest accrued, but not yet posted*. The accrued interest will post at the next statement date. I've only encountered this option with one credit union I used for a loan, never with any of my credit cards.

Comment: Likewise, I've never seen the "Pay in full" option, only "Statement balance" and "Full balance due" options--and sometimes the latter doesn't even appear.  (I wanted to pay the card to $0, I could figure out the full balance number but the website wouldn't allow me to pay more than the statement balance.)

Comment: I thought about it more and realized that I never actually paid any interest on any of my credit cards, so may be if I carry balance with non-zero APR it would show up? Not worth the money to experiment though :-D

Comment: Good point, that might be why I've never seen it, either.

Comment: If you do a cash withdrawal and wait one day, you'll get to see it.

Comment: @Nelson: Cash advance certainly falls into the category of "Not worth the money to experiment" -- you'd not only owe interest but also fees.

Comment: American Express has a pay entire balance option named "Total Balance," Apple Card has it under "Pay Card Balance". Pay in full isn't just interest accrued, but also new charges made between the closing of the last statement and now. You may want to pay these charges off early in the event you need to free up your credit line to make a large purchase.

Comment: @user71659 new charges are also included in the "full balance"

Comment: @littleadv No. Full balance due is statement balance minus credits and partial payments. It does not include charges since the last statement, because they are not yet _due_.

Comment: @user71659 that's not my experience. Maybe it differs by the bank. For my loans/credit lines "full balance" is consistently the current posted amount of debt, debits and credits included.

Comment: @littleadv It's invalid to compare any sort of non-revolving loan, since new charges can't be made, or conventional line of credit, because they do not have a grace period like credit cards.

Comment: @user71659 what do you mean? for each LOC I have, statement date is X, but due date is X+20++ days

Comment: @littleadv Conventional lines of credit accrue interest from the date of a charge. If you don't revolve a credit card, charges do not accrue interest from the date of a charge, through the statement date, to the statement due date. Therefore, it is advantageous not to pay charges made after the statement date, hence the distinction between "total balance" and "statement balance".

Comment: @user71659 but that's not the OP's use case. The OP is in fact revolving, so the charges for the OP do start accruing interest immediately. For people carrying balance on their credit cards there's no grace period.

Comment: @littleadv But the system doesn't know that, it offers the same options to all. Smarter systems, like my banks, will show options as necessary, like I've seen "remaining statement balance" only show up when a credit/partial payment has been made.

Comment: @user71659 yes it does. Believe me (I worked in a credit card company), when it comes to calculating interest charges their systems know everything they need to know.

Comment: @littleadv And you've worked at OP's tiny credit union? You can describe their software and web interface they're using?

Comment: @user71659 credit unions usually don't make their own systems, they either subscribe to a larger "corporate" credit union or buy off-the-shelf. The one I worked on was a very common off-the-shelf solution.

Comment: @littleadv , Upvote for you for the valiant effort, but my credit union threw you a curve ball. I posted the correct answer.

Comment: @InfiniteLoop and that is why the first comment you get with this type of questions is "go ask them directly" :)

Comment: @littleadv, yeah but I can't trust them. They are incompetent (not just this bank: e.g., I have caught Amex reps talking out of their butt _many times_ too where I showed them their own fine print according to which I was right and they were wrong. Not just reps too: I just tried to pay this credit card and picked option "PAY IN FULL" and the system gave me error message "Loan Payment Amount is greater than payoff".

Comment: So, I picked *Statement balance* instead, and that went through. The difference between STATEMENT BALANCE and PAY IN FULL in the "Select Payment Option" menu was $89, after I paid STATEMENT BALANCE amount, you would expect $89 left as balance, right? No, it's $69. DCU website and app used to be old, but impeccable, and now they hired a new VP for tech couple years ago, and she outsourced all tech development and everything is buggier than a freshman intern's hobby project. Sorry for the rant, my point is they cannot be trusted and customer service is dead for the sake of the holy bottom line.